# How do I find the next occurence of non NA value in a column of filtered range?

Tags: excel

I am having an excel sheet tracking member donations. I'm pasting the picture which will explain the situation. Essentially, I am trying to set N/A values (result of failed lookup) to the next non N/A value in the same column but having another column with same value as the row that had N/A column. I am unable to come up with formula for the same. I tried using the code fragments from solutions to problems that looked closer, but have not been able to make it work

Tried using multiple ways of SUMPRODUCT, INDEX MATCH combos etc. But none of them worked

[image: New image which is clear about how the values are set in Paid date column]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:**

This is an Array formula, enter with Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER($G4),$G4,SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(IF(($D4:$D$12=$D4)*($G4:$G$12<>"N/A"),($D4:$D$12=$D4)*$G4:$G$12,99999),1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow!! that worked. I need to fine tune this a little bit more. I will decode the formula and try that myself. Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem at all. Let us know if you need any further help adjusting the formula so that it works with your data set. Take care.

Comment: Well, I see a problem. It picks up the MAX value, whereas I am looking for the next N/A entry.

Comment: Hi @Dash, sorry for the misunderstanding. On your screenshot it says "*find the next non NA value* in column Stage Date that belongs to the same member (in this case, member = M1 and so the formula should evaluate to 31/05/19". Do you now want to have a formula which will return *"the next N/A entry"*? How would the final result look like (can you add a screenshot to your original question)?

Comment: No problem at all. I am pasting a new image here. Green colored cell highlight is for Member M2 and yellow for M1. For N/A in stage Date column, Paid date is next non N/A value in stage Date column for the same member. At the bottom of my original post, I have embedded a link to new image

Comment: Thanks @Dash, this is all clear now. I'm updating my answer right now.

Comment: No problem at all! Glad we had it sorted. Take care